# Adding an extra column that represents the difference between the closest difference of a previous column

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My scenario might be more easily explained through an example. Say I had the following data:

`Type   Time
 A      1
 B      3
 A      5
 B      9`

I want to add an extra column to each row that represents the minimum absolute value difference between all columns of the same type. So for the first row, the minimum difference between all times of type A is 4, so the value would be 4 for columns 1 and 3, and likewise, 6 for columns 2 and 4.

I am doing this in Spark and Spark SQL, so guidance there would be more useful, but if it needs to be explained through plain SQL, that would be a great help as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach is to use window functions.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{lag, min, abs}

val df = Seq(
  ("A", -10), ("A", 1), ("A", 5), ("B", 3), ("B", 9)
).toDF("type", "time")
```

First lets determine difference between consecutive rows sorted by time:

```scala
// Partition by type and sort by time
val w1 = Window.partitionBy($"Type").orderBy($"Time")

// Difference between this and previous
val diff = $"time" - lag($"time", 1).over(w1)
```

Then find minimum over all diffs for a given type:

```scala
// Partition by time unordered and take unbounded window
val w2 = Window.partitionBy($"Type").rowsBetween(Long.MinValue, Long.MaxValue)

// Minimum difference over type
val minDiff = min(diff).over(w2)

df.withColumn("min_diff",  minDiff).show


// +----+----+--------+
// |type|time|min_diff|
// +----+----+--------+
// |   A| -10|       4|
// |   A|   1|       4|
// |   A|   5|       4|
// |   B|   3|       6|
// |   B|   9|       6|
// +----+----+--------+
```

If your goal is to find a minimum distance between current row and any other row in a group you can use a similar approach

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{lead, when}

// Diff to previous
val diff_lag = $"time" - lag($"time", 1).over(w1)

// Diff to next
val diff_lead = lead($"time", 1).over(w1) - $"time"

val diffToClosest = when(
  diff_lag < diff_lead || diff_lead.isNull, 
  diff_lag
).otherwise(diff_lead)

df.withColumn("diff_to_closest", diffToClosest)

// +----+----+---------------+
// |type|time|diff_to_closest|
// +----+----+---------------+
// |   A| -10|             11|
// |   A|   1|              4|
// |   A|   5|              4|
// |   B|   3|              6|
// |   B|   9|              6|
// +----+----+---------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

tested in sql server 2008

create table d(
    type varchar(25),
    Time int
    )

```
insert into d
values ('A',1),
('B',3),
('A',5),
('B',9)

--solution one, calculation in query, might not be smart if dataset is large.
select *
, (select max(time) m from d as i where i.type = o.type) - (select MIN(time) m from d as i where i.type = o.type) dif 
 from d as o

--or this
 select d.*, diftable.dif from d inner join 
 (select type, MAX(time) - MIN(time) dif
from d group by type ) as diftable on d.type = diftable.type
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this:

```scala
val sc: SparkContext = ...
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

import sqlContext.implicits._

val input = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  ("A", 1),
  ("B", 3),
  ("A", 5),
  ("B", 9)
))

val df = input.groupByKey().flatMap { case (key, values) =>
  val smallestDiff = values.toList.sorted match {
    case firstMin :: secondMin :: _ => secondMin - firstMin
    case singleVal :: Nil => singleVal // Only one record for some `Type`
  }

  values.map { value =>
    (key, value, smallestDiff)
  }
}.toDF("Type", "Time", "SmallestDiff")

df.show()
```

Output:

```
+----+----+------------+
|Type|Time|SmallestDiff|
+----+----+------------+
|   A|   1|           4|
|   A|   5|           4|
|   B|   3|           6|
|   B|   9|           6|
+----+----+------------+
```